# Getting Unsupported block type error in Terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, autoscaling, aws-auto-scaling

I am getting Unsupported block type error related to autoscaling group. Specifically, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Unsupported block type
│ 
│   on main.tf line 67, in resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "ASG_asg":
│   67:   scaling_policy {
│ 
│ Blocks of type "scaling_policy" are not expected here.
```

My code is as below:

[image: Autoscaling code snippet]

I was trying to enable autoscaling when CPU usage exceeds a certain limit. Everything else is working except autoscaling where it is continuously giving error regarding metric module not required.

Comment: the resource doesnt have any block like that https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_group. maybe this should be an actual resource https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_policy

Comment: Please never post your code as screenshots. Copy and paste actual code lines, not an image.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to do indentation and without that, i wasn't able to upload code

Answer (score 3):

You will have to define the scaling policy (`aws_autoscaling_policy`) as a dependent resource instead of using it as a property of the `aws_autoscaling_group`. You can follow this pattern and configure it for your own context:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "bat" {
  name                   = "foobar3-terraform-test"
  scaling_adjustment     = 4
  adjustment_type        = "ChangeInCapacity"
  cooldown               = 300
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.bar.name
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "bar" {
  availability_zones        = ["us-east-1a"]
  name                      = "foobar3-terraform-test"
  max_size                  = 5
  min_size                  = 2
  health_check_grace_period = 300
  health_check_type         = "ELB"
  force_delete              = true
  launch_configuration      = aws_launch_configuration.foo.name
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. I made changes. But it is giving me new error.
Error: Argument or block definition required
│ 
│   on main.tf line 95:
│   95: }
│ 
│ An argument or block definition is required here.
Attaching block of code in another comment as i am not able to add whole code here